# How do I create a logout with Spring Security?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am trying to find a way just to setup a URL that will logout my user from the system. this is only for testing.  Right now we are using the default login page in spring secuirty

here is my spring-secuirty.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">


    <global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" />

    <http use-expressions="true">
        <intercept-url access="hasRole('ROLE_VERIFIED_MEMBER')" pattern="/ask-union**" />
        <intercept-url access="hasRole('ROLE_VERIFIED_MEMBER')" pattern="/ask-welfare**" />
        <intercept-url pattern='/*' access='permitAll' />

        <form-login default-target-url="/ask-union" />

        <logout logout-success-url="/" />

        <session-management session-fixation-protection="newSession">
            <concurrency-control max-sessions="1"/>
        </session-management>

    </http>

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider>
            <user-service>
                <user name="xxxxx@aol.com.dev" password="testing" authorities="ROLE_VERIFIED_MEMBER" />
               ser-service>

        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
</beans:beans>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add this line to your config

```
<logout logout-url="/sign-out"/>
```

Then if you have a link to that URL, then it will sign you out

(Add it just below your logout success config)

Comment: gonna need more to work with than that.. What happened? were there errors? how did they manifest themselves?

Comment: Also, as per @cabbagery's example below - roll the logout-url into the <logout> tag along with the logout-success-url

Answer (score 1):

I am a bit late on this. But answer may help others.

Use following code. logout-success-url is the URL you want take user after logging out.

```
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" access-denied-page="/denied">       
    <logout invalidate-session="true" logout-success-url="/landing" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" />
</http>
```

Answer (score 0):

Double-check the URL you're using -- the absolute path should be `your-domain/projectPath/sign-out`, per SJS's example. If the relevant portion of your spring-security.xml file looks like the following, it *should* work:

```
<http use-expressions="true">

. . .

    <logout
        logout-success-url="/"
        logout-url="/sign-out"/>
```

If you're able to authenticate, then simply browse to that path, and it should log you out. If it still doesn't try experimenting with the intermediary subdirectories specified in the URL, i.e. `your-domain/projectPath/some-subdirectory/log-out`.

Are you able to authenticate? It may not just be the logout aspect that's failing...

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party, but for future reference -- if you are interested in seeing how the security filters are instantiated and configured from XML, take a look at the following package:

```
org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers
```

For the logout filter configuration, this will be the LogoutConfigurer class. If you review the **LogoutConfigurer.createLogoutFilter()** method, you'll see how the default Logout filter is created. This implies that you can do the following in an @Configuration class:

```
@Bean
public LogoutFilter logoutFilter() {
    // NOTE: See org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.LogoutConfigurer 
    // for details on setting up a LogoutFilter
    SecurityContextLogoutHandler securityContextLogoutHandler = new SecurityContextLogoutHandler();
    securityContextLogoutHandler.setInvalidateHttpSession(true);

    LogoutFilter logoutFilter = new LogoutFilter("/", securityContextLogoutHandler);
    logoutFilter.setLogoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"));
    return logoutFilter;
}
```

If you have that, you can then either configure further by beans or have that bean picked up automatically since its method name is *logoutFilter()*